# A Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ with infinitely many $n$ such that $x_n = c$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

Is the following argument correct?

**Proposition**. If $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy sequence such that $x_n = c$ for infinitely many $n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = c$.

*Proof.* Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, there exists an $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall \, j,k\ge M$, we have $|x_j-x_k|<\epsilon$. Now, since $x_n = c$ for infinitely many $c$, then surely $x_r = c$ for some $r \ge M,$ implying that $|x_j-c|<\epsilon \,\,\forall j\ge M$, completing the argument.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Yes, it is correct. In similar way you can show that if there is a subsequence which converges to $c$ then the whole sequence converges to $c$.

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks for you help

Comment: "... implying that $|x_j-c|<\epsilon, \forall j\ge M$". Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, this completes the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told in the comments, your proof is fine.

Usually when I am asked to prove a statement that seems rather obvious, I tend to prove it by contradiction: this usually allows me to explore the intuitive feel I have for the result.

Assume the sequence converged to $l \neq c$. Then for $\epsilon = \frac{|c - l|}{2} $ $\exists N $ s.t. $i > N \implies |x_i - l| < \epsilon $, by definition of convergence. But this is absurd, because the sequence had infinitely many terms equal to $c $ and thus infinitely many $x_k = c $ with $k > N $.

Comment: This argument presupposes that the context is $\mathbb R$ or some other complete metric space, so that the sequence $(x_n)$ is guaranteed to converge and you only need to check that it can't converge to a wrong limit. But in fact the OP's proof works in any metric space (if you write $d(x,y)$ instead of $|x-y|$), even if the space isn't complete.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Indeed the OPs proof is more general, but I didn't think it was wrong to assume I was in $\mathbb R $, as the tag `real-analysis` suggests.

Comment: I appreciate your counsel RGS.